# How to use traits in Laravel models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Hello i'm laravel beginner

I want to make trait and use it in my model but at run time i got error that the trait is not found

my trait :

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

trait GeneralModel
{
    public static function testStaticFunction()
    {
        dd('test');
    }
}
```

my model :

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    use GeneralModel;
}
```

my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Comment;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function find()
    {
        Comment::testStaticFunction();
    }
}
```

error received

Trait 'App\GeneralModel' not found

Comment: Make sure your trait `GeneralModel.php` is in the same folder as the `Comment` model. Based on your namespace they should in the `app` folder.

Comment: Based on how you have things named regular old inheritance would probably be a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

In `composer.json` add this:

```
  "autoload"    : {
"classmap": [
  "database/seeds",
  "database/factories"
],
"files"   : [

  "app/GeneralModel.php" // <----------- ADD THIS 
],
"psr-4"   : {
  "App\\": "app/"
}},
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1):

Please check the GeneralModel.php in app folder. And execute the below command in your project root path.

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to Use

```
Composer dump-autoload
```

In Your command line

hope it's help